# Different density for each type of seed/plant?

Tags: farming-simulator-2013

In farming simulator 2013 you are able to plant different kind of seeds like rapeseed, wheat or barley. So I'm wondering if all seeds/plants have the same density?

Let's imagine I have a field which gives me 5t of rapeseed when I harvest everything on it. Will this field give me exact the same amount of wheat or has wheat a different density or whatever you call it, so that I will get more/less from the same field?

I'm asking this, because I don't see any reason for planting something else besides rapeseed in the early game, because the price per ton is nearly twice as much as every other plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my limited testing (5/7 harvests) if we consider wheat as a reference (100%) :

- **Barley** is roughly at 90% yield
- **Rapeseed** is roughly at 50% yield. That's why the price per ton is nearly twice as much)
- **Corn** has roughly the same yield (for pure corn not maize)
- **Sugar** beets are at 290% (but much more longer and costly to harvest)

Moreover wheat and barley yield straw, and corn is better used creating sillage I think (I have to test)

Comment: Mushu is correct. Also, since there are "great demands" for the different grains at various selling points from time to time, it can be worth storing up different grain types so you can get a higher price. When the great demand occurs, you would then sell all of that grain type to make up to twice the money.